# Should I repeat the JS postMessage script for every Setting in the WP Customizer?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Do I have to repeat the JS postMessage script for every Setting even if I have multiple equal Settings in the customizer?

I have a section with 8 settings that use the upload image control.

I intend to use the postMessage transport.

My question is, do I have to repeat the same JS script for each of those settings? or is there a way to like create a function ( to ) that applies to all of the settings and can be called for each one without all that amount of code?

I tried to do something like this:

`wp.customize( 'team_member_one', function( value ) {
        value.bind( ( to ) );
    });

```
wp.customize( 'team_member_two', function( value ) {
    value.bind( ( to ) );
});

wp.customize( 'team_member_three', function( value ) {
    value.bind( ( to ) );
});

function( to ) {
    $("[data-img]").each function() {
        if ($("[data-img]").data() < 9){
            if( to == '' ) {
                $("[data-img]").hide();
            } else {
                $("[data-img]").show();
                $("[data-img]").attr( 'src', to );
            }   
        }
    }
}  `
```

Needless to say that did not work, I'm a beginner.

This is my markup:

`<img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'team_member_one', '/images/team-member-1.jpg' ); ?>"
                  class="img-responsive team-gallery postmessage-1" id="team-img-one" data-img="1">`

And my fuctions.php settings code block:

`$wp_customize->add_setting(
      'team_member_one',
      array(
          'default'         => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/team-member-1.jpg',
          'transport'       => 'postMessage'
      )
  );`
All that like I said times 8, since I am providing 8 image uploaders of the same characteristics within the same section.

What would be my best bet? Thank you in advance.